# speakseasy nodeJS==> always get false

Tags: javascript, node.js, iis

hi guys hope every thing is going ok

i have a weird problem with speakseasy
every thing if going ok on my local machine when i uploaded to the iis the verify function always gets false

```
app.post("/verifySecret", async (req, res) => {
let data = await getSecret(req.body.email);
if (data == undefined) {
    res.send({
        "status": 404,
        "message": "Email account not registered"
    });
    return;
}

let valid = {
    "valid": speakeasy.totp.verify({
        secret: data.secret,
        encoding: "base32",
        token: req.body.token,
        window: 0
    }),
    "secret":data.secret,
    "token":req.body.token
};
res.send(valid);
```

});

i checked every thing the secret key come from database the token is working on my local machine but on iis not attached two photos at the same time

[first trial at iis machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fknMS.png)

[second trial at my local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnPEj.png)

both at the same time

Comment: There is no problem when debugging locally, but on IIS, the problem occurs?

Comment: on specific machine i investigate and found that this machine had some thing weird i tried to uninstall and reisntall the windows server but the problem still